# count the user input integer match with text file in c program

Tags: c, text, fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *file;
int word;
int num,num2;
int numcount1=0,numcount2=0;

printf("Please enter a keys: ");
if (scanf("%d %d", &num, &num2)==2 ){
} else {
    printf("Error:Must two integers");
}

file=fopen("data.txt","r");

while ((word=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
    fprintf(stdout, "%c",word);
    if (word == num)  numcount1++;
    if (word == num2)  numcount2++;
}
printf("'%d' is found %d times in the txt file\n",num,numcount1);
printf("'%d' is found %d times in the txt file\n",num2,numcount2);
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

data.txt

1 5 30
9 8 77
3 1 15
2 3 8

i want to ouput

```
[1111@11111 ~]$ ./count
 Please enter a keys: 1 2
'1' is found 2 times in txt file
'2' is found 1 times in txt file
```

my problem is input '1' can't count.
I have try to test (word == '1') numcount can count but also count '15' integer, totally 3 times nor 2 times

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not tag spam, this is a C question and should not be tagged C++

Comment: If this is for C why is it also tagged C++?

Comment: sorry i new in c program :( i'm not sure c and c++ no same.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &word)!=EOF){
    if (word == num)  numcount1++;
    if (word == num2)  numcount2++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to count number of occurences of keys ( which are only integers ) in file , following method seems good to me.

Read the complete file in unordered_map with key as that number and value as its count. This way your search will be efficient i.e O(1). This is definitely much better then searching through file on each input from user.

Whenever content of file changes just reload it into map again.